# Identify mobile application

Tags: authentication, mobile

Is it possible to identify (authenticate) a mobile application HTTP request ?
for example a request from a web server can by identified by the domain or IP, assuming I know from where it should come from I can accept the request or deny if it came from an unexpected origin.

doe's mobile application has some sort of unique id (that cannot be mimicked)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to make secure HTTP calls (webservice API) from a mobile app (a native compiled app), you can try the following approach:

**Edit:** This approach assumes that you can't rely on the user operating the app for authentication purposes (because then you could simply ask the user to type in a secure password in the app).

1. Assuming you are implementing the app, save some sort of secret API key in the code.
2. When the app makes an API call via HTTP, it will always be done using HTTPS (so everything is encrypted).
3. The app will send the secret API key as a URL parameter.
4. The server will authenticate by checking if the secret key is correct.

Sniffing the app traffic will not reveal the secret key (because of the HTTPS).

You are mostly vulnerable to someone reverse-engineering your app to discover the secret key inside. This can be made tough by using various obfuscation and anti-debugging techniques, but cannot be made truly impossible. As long as you're using a compiled language (like Objective-C, not JS for a web-app) this will already be tough without any special games. If you avoid placing your API key string as-is and compute it using some short code in the app, you've made it about 1000 times tougher to discover.

Without knowing more about your specific problem, it's hard to suggest alternate approaches. Please give more details if you are looking for something different.

Comment: I actually need to authenticate both web clients and mobile clients. The web client uses JavaScript so it is easy to get the secret key however your solution will work fine for mobile client. so if i identify the client type I can authenticate in different ways. Thanks!

Comment: This problem doesn't really have a solution. Since your app is given publicly to anyone (especially if it's JS), there is no way to truly differentiate between your app and an impostor which has full access to your source code.

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods used in practice. HTTP basic authentication (not much secure for mobile apps) and OAuth2 (secured compared to HTTP basic authentication).

- **HTTP Basic Authentication:** The process is simple for both technical writers of API services, and also developers using them:

A developer is given an API key (typically an ID and Secret). This API key usually looks something like this: 3bb743bbd45d4eb8ae31e16b9f83c9ba:ffb7d6369eb84580ad2e52ca3fc06c9d.

He is responsible for storing API key in a secure place on their server, so that no one can access it. He makes API requests to the API service by feeding the API key in the HTTP Authorization header along with the word 'Basic' (which is used by the API server to properly decode the authorization credentials). The key is also Base64 encoded.

For example key could be: 3bb743bbd45d4eb8ae31e16b9f83c9ba:ffb7d6369eb84580ad2e52ca3fc06c9d

encoded in base64: M2JiNzQzYmJkNDVkNGViOGFlMzFlMTZiOWY4M2M5YmE6ZmZiN2Q2MzY5ZWI4NDU4MGFkMmU1MmNhM2ZjMDZjOWQ=.

The API server reverses this process. When it finds the HTTP Authorization header, it will decode base64 result, read the API key ID and Secret and validate these tokens before allowing the request to be processed.

HTTP Basic Authentication is simple but for mobile apps securing the API Key is a main concern. HTTP Basic Authentication requires raw API keys to be sent over the wire for each request, thereby increasing chances of misuse in the long run.
Also it is impractical as you cannot safely embed API keys into a mobile app that is distributed to many users.

For instance, if you build a mobile app with your API keys embedded inside of it, a user could reverse engineer your app, exposing this API key, and abusing your service.

So HTTP Basic Authentication risky in open environments, like web browsers and mobile applications.

NOTE: Like all authentication protocols, HTTP Basic Authentication must be used over SSL at all times.

- **OAuth2 for Mobile API Security:**

  OAuth2 is an excellent protocol for securing API services from open devices, and provides a better way to authenticate mobile users via token authentication.

OAuth2 token authentication works from a user perspective (OAuth2 name it password grant flow):

When a user starts the mobile app he is  prompted for username or email and password.
The developer sends a POST request from app to API service with the login data included (over SSL). Then validate the user credentials, and create access token for the user which expires after a certain amount of time. This access token can be stored on mobile device, treating it like an API key which allows access to API service. When the access token expires user is prompted again for login details.

OAuth2 generates access tokens that can be stored in an open environment temporarily and are secure. It is secure because the access token are generated for temporary purpose and it reduces damage potential.

The token is stored according to the mobile platform used. For Android app, access tokens can be stored in Shared Preferences and for iOS app, in the Keychain.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you define "mobile application". Any application running on a mobile device ? Web browsing running on a mobile device ? What is a mobile device to you ?

Anyways, the general short answer, is that you can detect the device type using the User-Agent sent in the HTTP headers. All popular mobile browsers sends this. But be aware, that:

- It can be spoofed (easily)
- Some applications (ie iPhone or Android apps and similar) can be written in such a way, that they don't send a user agent with the HTTP requests. Best practice mandates to send the User-Agent though.

I don't know of a more reliable way to do this; and as long as stuff happens over HTTP there generally won't be any way of knowing anything about the client for certain. For mostly all the use cases, you will be alright with looking at the User-Agent.

You can buy access to User-Agent databases containing various device data, if applicable, two of such being [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) or [DeviceAtlas](https://deviceatlas.com/).